# How to render custom columns with a GenericTreeModel

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview

I have to display some data in a treeview. The "real" data model is huge and I cannot copy all the stuff in a TreeStore, so I guess I should use a `GenericTreeModel` to act like a virtual treeview. Btw, the first column is the classic icon+text style and I think I should declare a column with a CellRendererPixbuf ([faq sample](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.006.htp)), but I'm not sure what the model methods `on_get_n_columns()` and `on_get_value()` should return. It's both a Pixbuf and a string value for the same column.

Comment: Is your data huge because it has many rows or because each row comes with large data?

Comment: lot of rows. and columns too, but I need to show only some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [at the tutorial](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-CellRenderers.html), there is an example that packs two cell renderer to one column. The difference is that you are using a custom tree model and the behavior depends on how you *modeled* your model. If you have one column with the text and one column with the pixbuf you can use `set_attributes`:

```
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Pixbuf and text')
cell1 = gtk.CellRenderText()
cell2 = gtk.CellRenderPixbuf()
column.pack_start(cell1, True)
column.pack_start(cell2, False)
column.set_attribute(cell1, 'text', 0) # the first column contains the text
column.set_attribute(cell2, 'pixbuf', 1) # the second column contains the pixbuf
```

You can have otherwise a tree model with just one column with the objects that contains all you need, so just set a callback:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, text, pixbuf):
        self.text = text
        self.pixbuf = pixbuf

def cell1_cb(col, cell, model, iter):
    obj = model.get_value(iter)
    cell.set_property('text', obj.text)

def cell2_cb(col, cell, model, iter):
    obj = model.get_value(iter)
    cell.set_property('pixbuf', obj.pixbuf)

column = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Pixbuf and text')
cell1 = gtk.CellRenderText()
cell2 = gtk.CellRenderPixbuf()
column.pack_start(cell1, True)
column.pack_start(cell2, False)
column.set_cell_data_func(cell1, cell1_cb)
column.set_cell_data_func(cell2, cell2_cb)
```

I hope I give you an idea of what you can do and a start point. Disclaimer: I did not test the code.

Comment: it seems exactly what I was looking for (first case, separated icon and text in the model), I'll check it out tonight, thank you

Comment: ok I tried it and the solution was exactly the tutorial one: having a genericmodel or something else "behind" the treeview makes no differences. thank you.